# How can I prevent the warning No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding?

Tags: ssh, x11

Every time I initiate an ssh connection from my Mac to a Linux (Debian) I do get this warning:

```
No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

This also happens for tools that are using ssh, like git or mercurial.

I just want to make a local change to my system in order to prevent this from appearing.

Note: I do have X11 server (XQuartz 2.7.3 (xorg-server 1.12.4)) on my Mac OS X (10.8.1) and it is working properly, I can successfully start clock locally or remotely.

Comment: What command are you using to ssh?

Comment: @DerfK just `ssh hostname` but in my `~/.ssh/config` I added `ForwardX11 yes` some time ago. Still this is something that I do want  to have there.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (August 2017) I give up.   Bottom line is that even though it gives the error, it works.  I use `ssh -Y hostname` from Linux, and `ssh -x hostname` when using OpenSSH on Windows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found the cause, my `~/.ssh/config` was incomplete, you need both:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
```

My mistake was that I included only the ForwardX11 option.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is needed/relevant. `ForwardAgent` is used to allow keys cached in `ssh-agent` to pass through multiple nested SSH connections. It should not have any relevance to X11. And fwiw, according to some, it's not a good idea security-wise: https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/

Comment: That does not sound right, what helps is to actually turn off X11 forwarding or fix the xauth configuration to set it up. It is not related to ssh agents.

Comment: This solution did not work for me.

Comment: Is this `~/.ssh/config` on the macOS client or the Linux server?  I have these files on neither.  I do have a similar `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: On Mac OS, I also had to add "XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth"

Comment: My cause was different. This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100171/1139559

Answer (score 121):

None of the posted solutions worked for me.  My client (desktop) system is running macOS 10.12.5 (Sierra).  I added `-v` to the options for the `ssh` command and it told me,

```
debug1: No xauth program.
```

which means it doesn't have a correct path to the `xauth` program.  (On this version of macOS the path to `xauth` is nonstandard.)  The solution was to add this line to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (may be `/etc/ssh/config` in some setups) or in `~/.ssh/config` (if you don't have admin rights):

```
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Now the warning message is gone.

Comment: OMG. Years I’ve been trying to find a solution, and this worked. Years I say! Note that I did this by adding that line under the `Host *` entry in my `~/.ssh/config` file instead of editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. The only documentation I found for this was in `man sshd_config`.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I understand that at the moment XQuartz is not being well maintained due to lack of funding.   So I think porting issues like this are actually fewer than I would expect.

Comment: On High Sierra; this is the one that worked for me too.

Comment: Note you may experience this issue _even when your shell can find xauth_ in your PATH! I guess the ssh client is sanitizing your PATH for security reasons?

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.  I'm using Cygwin on Win7.  Adding "XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth", either under the "Host *" entry, or before that line, in ~/.ssh/config , made no difference.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr It's not working for me, either.  I'm using "terminal" on Ubuntu 16.04.  Did you find a solution, Mr. Karr?

Comment: This is the correct solution to the real problem in the question. Obviously you can turn the message of by disabling the X11 forwarding, but this is probably not what you want to do. You would have X11 forwarding on in your ssh config for a reason...

Comment: I also had issues to connect from a MacOS to a Linux box. In my case I also had to install `xauth` on the remote host. It was a CentOS box, so `yum -y install xauth` did the trick.

Answer (score 23):

## Letting Ubuntu bash on Windows 10 run `ssh -X`  to get a GUI environment on a remote server

- First

Install all the following. On Window, install `Xming`. On Ubuntu bash, use `sudo apt install` to install `ssh xauth xorg`.

```
sudo apt install ssh xauth xorg
```

- Second

Go to the folder contains `ssh_config` file, mine is `/etc/ssh`.

- Third

Edit `ssh_config` as administrator(USE `sudo`). Inside `ssh_config`, remove the hash `#` in the lines `ForwardAgent`, `ForwardX11`, `ForwardX11Trusted`, and set the corresponding arguments to `yes`.

```
# /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

- Forth

In `ssh_config` file, remove the front hash `#` before `Port 22` and `Protocol 2`, and also append a new line at the end of the file to state the xauth file location, `XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth`, remember write your own path of xauth file.

```
# /etc/ssh/ssh_config

#   IdentifyFile ...
    Port 22
    Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   ...
#   ...
    ...
    ...
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

- Fifth

Now since we are done editing `ssh_config` file, save it when we leave the editor. Now go to folder `~` or `$HOME`, append `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` to your `.bashrc` file and save it.

```
# ~/.bashrc
...
...
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
```

- Last

We are almost done. Restart your bash shell, open your `Xming` program and use `ssh -X yourusername@yourhost`. Then enjoy the GUI environment.

```
ssh -X yourusername@yourhost
```

The problem is also in Ubuntu subsystem on Windows, and the link is at

https://gist.github.com/DestinyOne/f236f71b9cdecd349507dfe90ebae776

Note: the linked text includes 2 typos (`XauthLocaion` instead of `XauthLocation`)

Comment: The question isn't about Windows.

Comment: On MacOS it is almost the same, the differences are instead of `Xming`, we should get `XQuartz`, and the `ssh_config` file is in a different location, mine is `/private/etc/ssh`.

Comment: And also, the last line for `ssh_config` will be: `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`

Comment: Edit needed: `XauthLocaion` -> `XauthLocation` (that edit is too small for me to make).

Comment: Besides installing `xming`, `ssh`,`xauth`, and `xorg` (step 1), the only thing needed for me was `export DISPLAY=localhost:0`

Comment: Thanks.  This helped me quite a bit.  My mistake was so simple.  The other directions I read way back for windows said to use DISPLAY=:0, but your advice to add localhost fixed my issue.

Comment: Setting `DISPLAY=localhost:0` saved me (e.g. I do `DISPLAY=localhost:0 ssh -X host`). I don't really dig what is happening here, but it was the missing piece for me. I am connecting from WSL to an Ubuntu server. There was no need for this dance for connecting from Arch to Arch.

Comment: xauth add :0 . `mcookie`  (From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100171/1139559)

Answer (score 14):

As noted, it seems that `xauth` on OS X Yosemite has regressed to an old version that doesn't work with XQuartz's `$DISPLAY` setting:

```
% xauth -V
1.0.9
% xauth generate $DISPLAY .
xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd(...)/org.macosforge.xquartz:0" in "add" command
```

Comment: I tested the same lines on OS X 10.11, and I do not get any error. Still same version of XQuartz.

Comment: @guest Your `xauth generate $DISPLAY .` command worked on my Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13), and it solved my `No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.` pb.

Comment: This isn't just OS X specific - running `xauth generate :0` made the warning disappear on my WSL/Debian client.

Comment: @sandyscott I use wsl2 with Debian and wanted the linux [gui apps on windows 11](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps), but I probably made the mistake to use debian instead of ubuntu. So maybe `wsl --update` was the bad guy. Now I want to revert to not get the warning the OP has which is annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. Adding one more line to [sorin](https://serverfault.com/a/422914/452336)'s solution worked for me.

On the client machine, edit your ssh config file with `vim ~/.ssh/config`

Then add these lines to it:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

You can double check your `xauth` location with:

```
which xauth
```

Comment: Not sure if this would really work because xauth location would be different on each remote machine. Yours looks like a MacOS one, but Linux has it in different location. I mostly started to disable ForwardX11 completly because I almost never user it.

Comment: @sorin maybe he updated the question because he explains how to find the right location in the answer. BTW: This works for me!

Answer (score 4):

This started happening to me after moving my Cygwin installation from one PC to another. The issue seemed to be the hostname change: the magic cookie no longer corresponded to the hostname of the new PC.

Running

```
touch ~/.Xauthority
xauth add :0 . `mcookie`
```

on the local Cygwin installation fixed the problem for me -- `xauth list` now listed a magic cookie associated with the correct hostname of the new PC, and the warning stopped appearing.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me! I'd just like to add that the command didn't work at first try for me, I was getting a `.../.Xauthority does not exist` error. To fix it I simply had to create an empty file using `touch .Xauthority` in my home folder, and then re-run the above `xauth` command again.

Comment: I did have an existing `~/.Xauthority` file from tinkering around trying to find the solution, thanks for letting me know it's essential!

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Host: Windows 11, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2), Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in MacOS at the moment.  I came across this too.  The fix for me involved adding the following to my .bash_profile

```
dispdir=`dirname $DISPLAY`
dispfile=`basename $DISPLAY`
dispnew="$dispdir/:0"
if [ -e $DISPLAY -a "$dispfile" = "org.x:0" ]; then
  mv $DISPLAY $dispnew
fi
export DISPLAY=$dispnew
```

Essentially the name for the file pipe associated with your X root can't be handled correctly, and thus needs correction.  :-)

Comment: I doubt this would solve the error in GUI OS X apps, like SourceTree.

Comment: Confirming it does work on Sierra for running emacs using X - as the Mac is the server. this should work broadly in cases where the client is on a remote machine

Answer (score 2):

i just removed ~/.Xauthority (destination machine) from my root folder and ssh -X 192.168.123.1  again and ik worked.

Comment: I can confirm this is an answer on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4.  **Removing ~/.Xauthority** on SSH server does the trick:  `~$ mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.bak`  A new magic cookie was automatically put back in ~/.Xauthority once I logged in again. No Bash scripting is required at all.

Answer (score 2):

Including

XAuthLocation /opt/local/bin/xauth
in ~/.ssh/config

in my macOS Sierra 10.12.6 worked for me. A small change from answer 7).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the problem of .Xauthority containing the Magic cookie
not forwarded, Fabby on http://askubuntu.com/questions/571116/ recommends 
on 2014-11-14 to add this line at the end of the .bashrc or . profile
to allow forwarding of xauth keys between users when calling su:

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

I added also previously:

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

to ensure remote called with ssh -X ̍@ will find it.

In my case .Xauthority is a symlink to original user /home//.Xauthority I su from...

```
  cd /home/<child_user>;ln -sf /home/<parent_user>/.Xauthority .xAuthority
```

with correct rights:

```
  sudo chown <parent_user> /home/<parent_user>/.profile
  chmod a+rw /home/<parent_user>/.profile
```

so it is accessible to  and to .  will be able to trigger apps on  and display X-windowed result on its local screen throughout proxy account !

TIP : Check xauth list...if reflects magic cookie on .

Answer (score 1):

My goal was get quiet ssh-based command line login t Linux hosts from my macOS client. E.g. I didn't want to see any banners or messages. Just setup cert-based login so I could type an alias at the and get a prompt on the host machine.  To accomplish that I did the following:

- On the **Debian 10 Linux** *host* I touched (e.g. created) 
  `~/.hushlogin`
- However, on **macOS Catalina** *ssh client* I was getting the message:

  ***No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.***

After confirming `xauth` binary location, I added`XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the macOS client, but that did *not* work for me when I used this command:

```
ssh -Y user@debian10
```

In the final analysis [@ssanch's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/955341/346965) *did* work for me. But before I discovered that solution I stumbled on a workaround that might help some people:

```
ssh -Yy user@host
```

Adding lowercase `-y` flag to the ssh command line causes it to send it's log output to syslog instead of stderr, and that allows for the desired quiet login also.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same trouble, I've tested all the other answers, nothing worked for me: launch xterm by ssh from local Windows 10 to Linux Debian 10 buster remote box.

The way worked for me is

1. Install Xming.exe under Windows and run it,
2. Then under Windows using PowerShell:

   ```
   $env:DISPLAY="localhost:0"
   ssh.exe -Y user@example.com
   ```

   instead of `ssh.exe -X user@example.com`.

`$env:DISPLAY` is mandatory. Shell environment variable `$DISPLAY` is automatically set by xauth or similar.

I've reported the detail on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845629/953097).